# memcpy error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I'm trying to copy one string to another in c using memcpy with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct fullName
{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
} NAME;

int main()
{              
    NAME myName, hisName;

    myName.firstName =  "aaaaaaa";
    hisName.firstName = "bbbbbb";

    memcpy(myName.firstName, hisName.firstName, sizeof(hisName.firstName));

    printf("myName.firstName = %s\n", myName.firstName);
    printf("hisName.firstName = %s\n", hisName.firstName);
}
```

and it gives Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error after running the program
I tried to declare `firstName` and `lastName` as pointer to an array of chars rather than pointer to char but the error persists . what am I missing ?! plz help...

FYI .. I'm working on Ubuntu 14 and I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)...

Comment: You need to terminate myName.firstName with a null char after you memcpy.

Comment: String literals can not be changed. the result is undefined  If could even change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `myName.firstName` and `hisName.firstName` with pointers to string literals. String literals cannot be modified, which is what's causing your error.

To achieve what you want, you can either declare `firstName` as a `char` array, or allocate memory to it (as a `char` pointer).

Array method:

```
typedef struct fullName
{
        char firstName[256]; // a sufficiently large number
        char lastName[256];
} NAME;

int main()
{              
        NAME myName, hisName;
        strcpy(myName.firstName, "aaaaaaa"); // You can't assign a string directly
        strcpy(hisName.firstName, "bbbbbb");
        memcpy(myName.firstName, hisName.firstName, sizeof(hisName.firstName));
        printf("myName.firstName = %s\n", myName.firstName);
        printf("hisName.firstName = %s\n", hisName.firstName);

}
```

Allocation method:

```
typedef struct fullName
{
        char* firstName;
        char* lastName;
} NAME;

int main()
{              
        NAME myName, hisName;
        size_t buffersize = 256; // a sufficiently large number
        myName.firstName = malloc(buffersize);
        hisName.firstName = malloc(buffersize); // same for lastName

        strcpy(myName.firstName, "aaaaaaa");
        strcpy(hisName.firstName, "bbbbbb");
        memcpy(myName.firstName, hisName.firstName, buffersize); // You can't use sizeof() as this will give the size of a pointer
        printf("myName.firstName = %s\n", myName.firstName);
        printf("hisName.firstName = %s\n", hisName.firstName);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In these statements

```
myName.firstName =  "aaaaaaa";
hisName.firstName = "bbbbbb";
```

you initialized pointers with addresses of string literals.

In next statement

```
memcpy(myName.firstName, hisName.firstName, sizeof(hisName.firstName));
```

you try to modify one of the string literals.

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Also this expression

```
sizeof(hisName.firstName)
```

returns size of the pointer itself. It is not the same as the size of the corresponding string literal.

The valid program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct fullName
{
    char firstName[8];
    char lastName[8];
} NAME;

int main()
{              
    NAME myName = { "aaaaaaa" };
    NAME hisName = { "bbbbbb" };

    memcpy( myName.firstName, hisName.firstName, sizeof( hisName.firstName ) );

    printf( "myName.firstName = %s\n", myName.firstName );
    printf( "hisName.firstName = %s\n", hisName.firstName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not crash in MSVC, it produced the output:

```
myName.firstName = bbbbaaa
hisName.firstName = bbbbbb
```

Notice that only 4 chars from `hisName` have been copied to `myName`. That is because

```
sizeof(hisName.firstName)
```

is 4 on your platform, the size of the pointer. But manipulating such strings is Undefined Behaviour anyway.